# Is there a Word-like real-time collaborative word-processor that can be installed on a private network

Tags: microsoft-word, real-time

I am looking for a tool where users can work collaboratively in real-time on a mutiple documents, but that can be installed on a private network.

Basically a Google Docs like environment that can run on a private network.

I have found tools such as SubEthaEdit and Gobby, but they are geared to coders whereas I need a rich-text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Corel's **[Wordperfect Lightning](http://www.brothersoft.com/corel-wordperfect-lightning-65244.html)** is a free, lightweight collaborative word processor.

[image]

Comment: This product still requires internet connectivity and stores data on corel's servers.